# Ajax request doesn't auto trigger on form change

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
<form>
  <select name="select-1">
    <option value="option-1">Option 1</value>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</value>
  </select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I have a form that when the button is clicked, it populates a div with html content from an Ajax request without any page reload ( its done in the backend, cant say much more because its not my area of expertise ). When the submit button is clicked, it works as expected, but the behaviour I want is for the Ajax request to auto-trigger when the form has an option selected, without the need to press the button.

```
  $(document).on(
    "change",
    "select[name=select-1]",
    function(e) {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        $(document)
          .find("form")
          .submit();
      }
    }
  );
```

The problem here is that the form submits and reloads the page, not triggering the Ajax request. I have also tried to trigger a click event on the button itself:

```
  $(document).on(
    "change",
    "select[name=select-1]",
    function(e) {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        $(document)
          .find("button")
          .click();
      }
    }
  );
```

.. but nothing happens.

Comment: .submit() is not an AJAX call. 
You need to learn more about the jQuery `$.ajax()` ,`$.get()`, and `$.post()` methods.

Comment: If I click the button it works perfectly. Isn't there a way to trigger a button click when the select has a value ?

Comment: You need to add an event listener to the select options. You can do it with jQuery on change function.

Comment: I did that in the second example of code I posted. Maybe the code is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try something like this, as suggested by @Anjana. try to submit form data 
// using ajax.

$(document).on(
    "change",
    "select[name=select-1]",
    function(e) {
      if ($(this).val()) {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("select-1", $(this).val());
        $.ajax({
          url: {your url},
          method: "post", 
          data: formData,
          success: function(data) {
            div.innerHTML = data;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if you are using AJAX, you should trouble with `form`. You only need something to trigger the call. That can simply be a button.

```html
<select id="menu" name="select-1">
  <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
</select>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Select the value that the user has selected in the select menu with:

```
const selection = $( "#menu option:selected" ).text();
```

Then use the [`$.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function provided by jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#submit').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<CHANGE HERE>",
      data: { selection: selection },
      dataType: "json"
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used button type ="submit", which makes the page reload. So remove type submit from your button and use ajax or use e.prevent default() like

```
$("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
          url: url, //type your url,
          method: "post", 
          data: data,
          success: function(data) {

          },
          error: function(data){

          }
});
```

After that on change when you submit the form on change event as you are doing, it will trigger the Ajax request and work as you expect.

Learn  More about Ajax [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the jQuery code you are using is not AJAX, you can learn more about jQuery and AJAX from their documentation here:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
<!--HTML CODE-->
<form>
      <select name="select-1">
        <option value="option-1">Option 1</value>
        <option value="option-2">Option 2</value>
      </select>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here's the jQuery code that actually uses AJAX.

A selector is used to get the `<select></select>` and then we set an event listener to listen when the object is changed.

**UPDATE:** This now allow you to attach event listener to dynamically created elements

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(body).on('change', "select[name=select-1]", function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://example.com",
            method: 'GET',
            data: {"id": 123, "value": $('select[name=select-1]').val()}
        })
        .done(function (){
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function (){
            alert("error" + $('select[name=select-1]').val());
        });
    })
});
```

You can change the url in the AJAX, as well as method with GET or POST, and the data to be sent to the URL.

After that, if the AJAX request is successful, the code in the .done() section will be executed.

Similarly, if the request fails, the code in fail() will be executed.

Comment: The problem is, the Ajax request is done in the backend, which renders a template that will get inserted in a specified div.

Comment: You mean the `<option></option>` are dynamically generated?

Comment: Yes, and also the response template.

Comment: Try the updated code, it should work for newly created elements. The trick is to select the parent of the dynamically created element, but specific the element at the second parameter of the on() function.